# How do I set a limit on how many times I can use slideToggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I rapidly click the div on an HTML website that calls the `.slideToggle()` method, it will continuously open and close as many times I click the button. The issue comes that after I stop clicking, the `<div>` will still open and close itself and keep on doing so until it reaches the number of times I clicked it. If you rapidly hit "Toggle" logo, this demo has the same issue. See this example: https://css-plus.com/examples/2010/03/slidetoggle/index

```
$("#examplebutton1").click(function()
{
    $("#examplecontent1").slideToggle(500);
});
```

I originally tried inserting the `.slideToggle()` method, but that obviously didn't work. Is there a way I can make it so the method would work if the div if fully extended or fully closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `setTimeout` and a global variable to check if a transition is already going on:

```
let transitionIsHappening = false;
$("#examplebutton1").click(function() {
    if (transitionIsHappening) return;
    transitionIsHappening = true;
    $("#examplecontent1").slideToggle(500, () => transitionIsHappening = false);
});
```

Comment: A cleaner solution would be to use slideToggle's callback rather than a separate setTimeout: https://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: @JonUleis Thanks for the great catch! I didn't realize `.slideToggle()` was a jQuery function. I've edited my answer.